# Updating the values in core data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, core-data

I have a list of expenses and their price stored in core data in view1.
I am retrieving these values in view2 and showing them in a tableView.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//Displayin the values in a Cell.

NSManagedObject *records = nil;
        records = [self.listOfExpenses objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        self.firstLabel.text = [records valueForKey:@"category"];
        NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[records valueForKey:@"date"]];
        NSString *dateWithInitialFormat = dateString;
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];
        NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateWithInitialFormat];
        [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
        NSString *dateWithNewFormat = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
        self.secondLabel.text = dateWithNewFormat;
        [dateFormatter release];
        NSString *amountString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[records valueForKey:@"amount"]];
        self.thirdLabel.text = amountString;
}
```

if i click on a row in the tableView it should navigate to view1 and i should be able to edit the values and update in the core data.Can any one tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: You'll probably use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: i know how to navigate but i dont understand how to update the values.

Comment: `[nameOfManagedObjectContext save:&error]`

Comment: actually when a row is tapped and navigated to view1 i want 2 things to happen.the values in the cell should be displayed in their textfields where we added them from.and the edited value should get updated in the core data.

Answer (score 1):

First, i recommend you to use [NSFetchedResultsController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for populating table view from core data(vice versa). Second, when you clicked on an individual row from tableview, use the delegate of tableview as like i do below(for this in app delegate i declared an int variable called selectedMesageIndex)

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   //YourAppDelegate is the name of your app delegate class
   YourAppDelegate* sharedDa= (YourAppDelegate *)([[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]);

   sharedData.selectedMesageIndex = indexPath.row;

}
```

And when you come back to the first view conrtoller, fetch data from core data and get the data parameter of selected index path(again via  `sharedData.selectedMesageIndex` )..